# in VS2019 when I change cshtml code I have to run application again. Is there any option in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019

whenever I only change cshtml.cs code in my asp.net core web application, all the time I've to run application again. So, is there any helpful details to solve this problem please tell.

I checked the VS2019 settings and all but couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Browser Link` feature to achieve it.

Install these two packages into your project:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

Update the project’s `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Call `UseBrowserLink` in the `Startup.Configure` method:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       app.UseBrowserLink();
   }
```

Enable Browser Link

[image]

Every time after you change your code in cshtml.cs, you can just click this Flame icon and refresh the browser, The new code will apply.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will check this method in my project.